# Setting parameters on collection methods using Backbone.Rpc

Tags: backbone.js

Using the Backbone.Rpc plugin [ https://github.com/asciidisco/Backbone.rpc ] I am attempting to send parameters on the read method when fetching a collection.  When working with a single model instance you can add parameters to a method call by setting the value of a model attribute.

```
var deviceModel = Backbone.model.extend({
  url: 'path/to/rpc/handler',
  rpc: new Backbone.Rpc(),
  methods: {
    read: ['getModelData', 'id']
  }
});
deviceModel.set({id: 14});
deviceModel.fetch(); // Calls 'read'

// Request created by the 'read' call
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getModelData","id":"1331724849298","params":["14"]};
```

There is no corresponding way that I am aware of, to do a similar thing prior to fetching a collection as there is no 'set' method available to backbone collections.

```
var deviceCollection = Backbone.collection.extend({
  model: deviceModel,
  url: 'path/to/rpc/handler',
  rpc: new Backbone.Rpc(),
  methods: {
    read: ['getDevices', 'deviceTypeId']
  }
});
// This is not allowed, possible work arounds?
deviceCollection.set('deviceTypeId', 2);
deviceCollection.fetch();
// Request created by the 'read' call
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getDevices","id":"1331724849298","params":["2"]};
```

Is it possible to pass parameters to collection methods using Backbone.Rpc? Or do I need to pass collection filters in the data object of the fetch method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated Backbone.Rpc (v 0.1.2) & now you can use the following syntax to add "dynamic"
arguments to your calls.

```
var Devices = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'path/to/my/rpc/handler',
    namespace: 'MeNotJava',
    rpc: new Backbone.Rpc(),
    model: Device,
    arg1: 'hello',
    arg2: function () { return 'world' },
    methods: {
        read : ['getDevices', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
    }
});

var devices = new Devices();
devices.fetch();
```

This call results in the following RPC request:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"MeNotJava/getDevices","id":"1331724850010","params":["hello", "world", "arg3"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah,
okay, this is not included at the moment, but i can understand the issue here.
I should be able to add a workaround for collections which allows the RPC plugin to read
collection properties.

```
var deviceCollection = Backbone.collection.extend({
    model: deviceModel,
    url: 'path/to/rpc/handler',
    rpc: new Backbone.Rpc(),
    deviceTypeId: 2,
    methods: {
        read: ['getDevices', 'deviceTypeId']
    }
});
```

Which will then create this response:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getDevices","id":"1331724849298","params":["2"]};
```

I will take a look this evening.

Comment: Hi, any solution for this issue?